# SQL return 100 random rows for each age

Tags: mysql, sql, random, group-by

For each of the i.Age(0-100) I want to return 100 random rows for each age with the selected data. I am unsure if I should be using a while loop to accomplish this or possibly a group by with a limit somehow? I've looked at a fair few different examples but I'm still quite confused.

```
SELECT, i.name, i.Gender, i.Age, i.MP, b.score
FROM i
INNER JOIN b on b.name=i.name
WHERE i.MP='F'
AND i.gender='F'
AND b.score<=-1
AND i.age = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 100
```

At the moment the above query works but it only returns 100 random rows for the age of 0. I've looked at a fair few examples but cannot grasp whether I should use a group by or possibly a while loop. There are over 10,000,000 rows in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use user defined variables below query will give you one record per each distinct age,inner query is just checking the for same ages and giving rank to them like for 4 same ages (age = 1) rank will be 1,2,3,4 and when age =2 then rank number will start from 1 again and where filter of outer query is filtering rows to show the where rank is 1 so for each distinct age you will get one row and they are ordered randomly

```
SELECT  c.name, c.Gender, c.Age, c.MP, c.score
FROM (
SELECT i.name, i.Gender, i.Age, i.MP, b.score,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = i.Age THEN @r + 1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
@g:=i.Age
FROM i
INNER JOIN b ON b.name=i.name
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @g:=NULL ,@r:=0) a
WHERE i.MP='F' AND i.gender='F' AND b.score<=-1
ORDER BY  i.Age, RAND()
) c
WHERE c.rownum = 1
ORDER BY c.Age
LIMIT 100
```

let suppose your joined query give you  the results as

### Sample data set

```
name   gender  Age  Mp score
============================
test1  male    1    1   10
test2  male    1    1   10
test3  male    1    1   10
test4  male    2    1   10
test5  male    2    1   10
test6  male    3    1   10
test7  male    4    1   10
test8  male    4    1   10
.....
```

Now using the inner query in my answer will give you the result sets with rank column as below

### Inner query result set

```
name   gender  Age  Mp score rank
==================================
test2  male    1    1   10    1
test1  male    1    1   10    2
test3  male    1    1   10    3
test4  male    2    1   10    1
test5  male    2    1   10    2
test6  male    3    1   10    1
test7  male    4    1   10    1
test8  male    4    1   10    2
```

As in above result set you can see for age = 1 have 3 rows and their ranks are different 1,2,3 same example for age = 2 ranks are 1,2 same for age = 4,Now in my answer the outer query will filter out the result where rank = 1 so the final result set will contain one row for each distinct as see below result set

### Final output

```
name   gender  Age  Mp score rank
==================================
test2  male    1    1   10    1
test4  male    2    1   10    1
test6  male    3    1   10    1
test7  male    4    1   10    1
```

The random ordering part is done at the inner query as you can see the order by part `ORDER BY  i.Age, RAND()` it will first order the age in ascending manner and then for same age values it will further order results randomly.Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thank you for this, sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question. How would I modify this to return 100 random rows for each individual age?

Comment: Thank you. So this will return 100 random rows for age 0, 100 random rows for age 1, 100 random rows for age 2 and so on for each age? I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the last 3 lines to 
WHERE c.rownum <= 100
ORDER BY c.Age
I assume this will now return 100 random rows for each age. So 10,000 rows total. You have been very helpful thank you.

Comment: @Mitchell yes it will give you 100 random rows for each user

Comment: @Mitchell Sorry it was age instead of user in my previous comment :)

Comment: Hey, so I'm having problems with running the query. I ran the exact same query in your answer and it still returns every single instance of every age in the database (millions or rows). So the rownum isn't working correctly. I tried a few things but cannot manage to fix it. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61816/discussion-between-m-khalid-junaid-and-mitchell).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate via while loop from Age 0 to 100, and pass Age variable to where clause.

Comment: This will work, but 101 queries is a lot and will have high performance cost. (I don't know anything better though)