# MySQL get date of record where count was achieved

Tags: mysql

This honestly sounds like a job for a function in MySql but I'm wondering if there's a way to make a query that selects the date of the record that achieves the count = x

Setup: 1000 records each having the same qualifying conditions.. lets say user_id and visit information and a create_date

Desired Query result: Select the date of the 100th visit

```
SELECT create_date
FROM user_visits
HAVING COUNT(id) = 100;
```

Comment: Do you have any auto increment column ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Yes, the primary key of the visits table.

Comment: `COUNT(id)`, or `COUNT(UNIQUE id)`, that one makes a huge difference... (or is `id` the primary key of the table?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use order by on your auto_increment column and limit 99,1 to pick 100th visit

```
SELECT create_date
FROM user_visits
ORDER BY your_auto_increment_column
LIMIT 99,1
```

Comment: okay, this is quite technically the answer to my question. so I'm probably going to open a new question for the next part, but now I need to do this for multiple users and multiple levels.. so I'm thinking a group by user_id for multiple users and then how do I get the 100th and 900th visit date?

Comment: @AlanAsher Yes this can be possible by using user defined variables to assign a rank to rows that belongs to same user,Today i have given an answer to similar question you are asking but in that case there were same ages and in your case you have users [*SQL return 100 random rows for each age*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987083/sql-return-100-random-rows-for-each-age/25987337#25987337),Yes please ask new one i will try to answer that one